# Create xsd format to have auto-generated class in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am working on a project which needs to pass request to the API in the xsd format. I just need to add an additional parameter as xsd to successfully pass the modified parameter in request. I am new to xsd so I searched over internet for the changes that I need to make.

```
<v1:Major>
    <v1:Minor11>
        <v1:Minor111>123456</v1:Minor111>
        <v1:Minor112>abcd</v1:Minor112>
    </v1:Minor11>
    <v1:Minor12>
        <v1:Minor121>123456</v1:Minor121>
        <v1:Minor122>12345</v1:Minor122>
        <v1:Minor123>123456</v1:Minor123>
        <v1:Minor124>123456</v1:Minor124>
        <v1:Minor125>abcdef</v1:Minor125>
    </v1:Minor12>
    ***<v1:Minor13>abcdef123</v1:Minor13>*** {I need to add this}
    <v1:Minor14>
        <v1:ChargeTotal>15</v1:ChargeTotal>
        <v1:Currency>INR</v1:Currency>
    </v1:Minor14>
</v1:Major>
```

I simply added
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Minor13" type="v1:String1024max"/>
I found this from somewhere. This gives me soap request exception . Also in java it creates an auto generated file by the class name Minor13.java with empty class. I want that this class be created so that I can a string input to this element and add that Minor13 to the Major element via java. I have the code in place but just need to do this bit. Can someone help ?

Comment: Can not see any XSD. What XSD you are talking about?

Comment: Can you let me know how to create an XSD from the above so that I can pass a string value to the Minor13 element ?

Comment: Can not see how this will help you. If you have a SOAP API, which validates your XML data based on an XML schema definition (XSD), then the XSD exists already and you have to extend it.